# Apache Camel Test Support with POJO and OSGI reference bean

Tags: junit, apache-camel, osgi

I am creating a Junit Test using `CamelTestSupport`. The Camel Route has few references to POJO Beans and OSGI references.The OSGI reference is an Interface.I had used `SimpleRegistry` to capture the POJO beans using Java DSL. However, I do not know how to add OSGI reference or `OSGIServiceRegistry` for the purpose.

How do I had OSGI reference and POJO Beans along with the OSGI references in the registry so that `CamelTestSupport` can trigger the test method?

For reference-

Camel version - 2.13.2

Junit version - 4.11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use blueprint, you can try to use `CamelBlueprintTestSupport` rather than `CamelTestSupport`. If it does not help, you can look at the code of `CamelBlueprintTestSupport`, specially the `createBundleContext()` method, wich registers some services at startup.

Comment: This answer reminded me of `@Override
protected void addServicesOnStartup(Map<String, KeyValueHolder<Object, Dictionary>> services) {
    services.put("myService", asService(myService, "beer", "Carlsberg"));
}` which may help the OP too (it's in camel-test-blueprint too). This example and more documentation can be found here: http://camel.apache.org/blueprint-testing.html

Comment: I started using the CamelBlueprintTestSupport.  After few initial error with the blueprint config, I was able to get started. However, the test method is now having trouble starting with bean exception.  org.apache.camel.NoSuchBeanException: No bean could be found in the registry.  How do we add the POJO bean reference to registry in case of BlueprintTestSupport ?

Comment: I used the CamelBlueprintTestSupport with Overridden addServicesOnStartup() & getBlueprintDescriptor() methods the Test was able to resolve the beans. Thank you for suggesting to use the CamelBlueprintTestSupport along w/ OSGI Blueprint.